# How could I set the width of UIPickerView

Tags: swift, uikit

[my interface screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftwrk.png)

I tried to set the width of a UIPickerView, but it didn't work.
For example, i used

```swift
 class Coordinator : NSObject,UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource{
...
 func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
            
            let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:128,height:60))
...
return view
}
...
}
```

above code,could only change the width of the red block.
i want to change the width of the whole picker,including the half-opacity-block.

```swift
struct CustomPicker : UIViewRepresentable{
...
func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<CustomPicker>) -> UIPickerView {
let picker = UIPickerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 60))
return picker
}
}
```

above code didn't work .

In addition , is there some func could hide/remove/custom the half-opacity-mask ?
waiting for you help ! thx a lot :) !

Here's whole codes.

```swift
// ContentView

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var selectedWeight : dataListItemModel = dataListItemModel(label: "1KG", value: 1)
    @State var selectedTimes : dataListItemModel = dataListItemModel(label: "1RM", value: 1)
    
    let timesDataList : [dataListItemModel] = [
        dataListItemModel(label: "1RM", value: 1),
        dataListItemModel(label: "2RM", value: 2),
        dataListItemModel(label: "3RM", value: 3),
    ]
    let weightDataList : [dataListItemModel] = [
        dataListItemModel(label: "1.25KG", value: 1.25),
        dataListItemModel(label: "2.5KG", value: 2.5),
        dataListItemModel(label: "5KG", value: 5),
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
                CustomPicker(selected: self.$selectedWeight,dataList: weightDataList,width: 200)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

```swift
// CustomPicker

import SwiftUI
import UIKit


struct dataListItemModel : Identifiable {
    let id : String = UUID().uuidString
    let label : String
    let value : Double
    
    init(label : String,  value : Double)  {
        self.label = label
        self.value = value
    }
    
}



struct CustomPicker : UIViewRepresentable{
    
    @Binding var selected : dataListItemModel

    let dataList : [dataListItemModel]
    let width : CGFloat
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> CustomPicker.Coordinator {
        return CustomPicker.Coordinator(parent1: self)
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<CustomPicker>) -> UIPickerView {
        let picker = UIPickerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/3, height: 60))

        picker.dataSource = context.coordinator
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
  
//        picker.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        
        return picker
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIPickerView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<CustomPicker>) {
        
    }
    
    class Coordinator : NSObject,UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource{
        
        var parent : CustomPicker
        let dataList : [dataListItemModel]
        let width : CGFloat
        
        init(parent1 : CustomPicker) {
            parent = parent1
            dataList = parent1.dataList
            width = parent1.width
        }
        
        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
            return dataList.count
        }
        
        func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
//            pickerView.subviews.forEach({
//                // $0.frame = CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:width,height:60)
//1
//                $0.isHidden = $0.frame.height < 1.0
//            })
            return 1
        }
        
        
        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
            
            let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:width,height:60))
            let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.width, height: view.bounds.height))
            
            label.text = dataList[row].label
            label.textColor = .white
            label.textAlignment = .center
            label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 22,weight:.bold)
            label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
            label.numberOfLines = 1
            view.backgroundColor = .red
            
            
            view.addSubview(label)
            
            view.clipsToBounds = true
            view.layer.cornerRadius = 8
            
            return view
        }
        
        
        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, widthForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
            return width
        }
        
        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, rowHeightForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
            return 60
        }
        
        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
            self.parent.selected = dataList[row]
        }
        
        
    }
}

class Host : UIHostingController<ContentView>{
    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle{
        return .lightContent
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using SwiftUI or UIKit? Your title and tag say SwiftUI, but your code is UIKit. Either way, please include the code that you've used to set up the picker.

Comment: hi sir,I'm trying to custom a picker,you know. the pickerStyle is not on public. So i tried to use Uikit. By using UIViewRepresentable

Comment: You're leaving out a ton of code. You have a coordinator listed now, but you don't show ever hooking up the coordinator as the delegate, for example. Can you include a [mre]?

Comment: @wildz not on GitHub -- include the relevant code here. Links can expire and they aren't searchable here on SO.

Comment: @jnpdx I'm new here. Thx for your suggestions. I've post code , in the main floor.